# Search keywords in PDF blob - Azure Search

Tags: azure, metadata, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to search for keywords contained in the metadata of a PDF doc. I am unsure if this is possible. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Here is an example of the keywords/tags in a PDF I am referring to
[image]

I know it is possible to add fields to the search index, but am unsure how to map it. I have tried the following but it did not work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the keywords metadata would work -

1. Adding a keywords (metadata) to the pdf file would not work as only selected custom metadata tags are supported for pdf. 
   Refer this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage
2. A work around to this problem could be add metadata tag to the pdf file blob itself.
   [image]
3. After we create a index in azure search for ("All Metadata"/Storage Metadata) this key starts appearing under the list of field names to select(search/retrieve/filter etc.).
   [image]
4. And finally we can search on the custom keywords now.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for this, this makes perfect sense. The only problem is that we want the user to be able to add the comments themselves (when creating the PDF). This is not something we would want to maintain, and they do not have access to the azure portal. But I guess this is probably the only way

Answer (score 0):

The Keywords tag is not one of the ones we support through the metadata_ format (the ones that are, are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#content-type-specific-metadata-properties)).  If you add a field to the index called "Keywords", does it extract it?  Also, I if you look at the properties of the PDF in something like Azure Storage Explorer, I assume this keyword metadata is still there and it is called "Keywords".  If not, this might give some additional insight.

Comment: Tried adding an index named "Keywords" , but the search does not extract it either.

Comment: Currently, Azure Search does not support extracting PDF `keyword` metadata. Please add a suggestion on our [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) and we'll consider adding this. Thanks!